# Show form errors when updating an object from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a form in an `account_settings` controller that updates a `user` object through the `users_controller`. The error messages are not getting passed through. Here's a look at the code.

account_settings/account.html.haml

```
= form_for @user, :url => { :controller => "users", :action => "update", :id => @user.id } do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    .alert.alert-error
      %h4
        Please address the following errors:
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  form stuff...
```

account_settings_controller

```
def account
  @user = current_user
end
```

users_controller

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:notice] = "User was successfully updated."
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
```

The form will not update but there are no error messages getting passed back. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are returning a redirecting. The `@user` object does not persist across the redirect. You should be doing something like:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:notice] = "User was successfully updated."
    redirect_to :back
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Here, we redirect when the update is successful, but if not, we render the `edit` action. Hence we have access to `@user`, and your errors would be present in `@user.errors`

Comment: The problem doesn't lie with the partial; I probably shouldn't have put the code on here like that in first place cause it's confusing. I've updated my question so it's more to the point.

Comment: Aaaaah! That indeed fixed my problem. Thank you!